# How to replace empty lines followed by a specific string by this string?

Tags: awk, sed

With `sed` or `awk` or whatever, how to replace empty lines followed by a specific string (for instance `&` or `\end{align}`) by this string (hence `&` or `\end{align}`)?

As an example, here is the initial file (**edit**: less ambiguous example):

```latex
The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

Indeed, the quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

\begin{align}


& foo

& bar

\end{align}

The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

Indeed, the quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.
```

and here is what I'd like to get:

```latex
The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

Indeed, the quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

\begin{align}
& foo
& bar
\end{align}

The quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.

Indeed, the quick brown fox jumps over the sleazy dog.
```

Comment: Within `\begin` and `\end`, would it be a mistake to remove *all* blank lines?

Comment: @glennjackman In LaTeX, blank lines are forbidden within *math* environments such as `align`, `equation`, etc. Within other environments, blank lines are allowed, and removing them could lead at least to unexpected results.

Comment: So, remove blank lines from _any_ begin-end blocks, or just a subset of `\begin{XYZ}`?

Comment: @glennjackman No, not from any begin-end blocks: only the "math" ones (see e.g. the ones provided by the [`amsmath` package](https://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GNU sed` with extended regex support (-E) to aid in regex writing.

```
sed -Ei -e '
  /./b
  :a
    $q;N
  /\n$/ba
  s/^\n+(&|\\(begin|end)\{align\})/\1/
' file
```

Idea is to start collecting empty lines and stop when a nonempty line is seen. Then the regex will check whether the chunk of empty lines is followed by any one of the following three lines:

- a line starting with an ampersand `&`
- a line starting with \begin{align}
- a line starting with \end{align}

Then we delete these specific empty lines.

Comment: AFAICS, this doesn't remove in place and I have to add at the end of this command something like `> tmp && mv -f tmp file`. Instead, I tried to add the `i` flag to `sed` but that returns the error `sed: -e expression #1, character 71: Content of \{\} invalid`.

Comment: Added the inplace edits flag -i . You may rerun now.

Answer (score 1):

With `pcregrep` in multiline mode:

```
pcregrep -M '^(?!\s+^(&|\Q\end{align}\E))' < file
```

greps for starts of lines that are not followed by one or more whitespace (includes newline), the start of another line and wither `&` or `\end{align}`.

Or with `perl`:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/^\s+^(&|\Q\end{align}\E)/$1/gm' < file
```

Answer (score 0):

This removes *all* blank lines in the align block:

```bsh
sed '/\\begin/,/\\end/ { /^$/d; }' file
```

The semicolon is required for the BSD sed on my Mac but not for GNU sed.

It's trickier to match specific block types. The straightforward method is

```bsh
sed '
  /\\begin{align}/,/\\end{align}/ { /^$/d; }
  /\\begin{equation}/,/\\end{equation}/ { /^$/d; }
' file
```